# Connect C# Application with an Insert Into in an API

Tags: c#, php, wpf

I have an API with an Insert Into command, that is looks like this :

```
index.php

 elseif ($tag == "addpatient" && $isAdmin) {
    // Request type is insert a patient
    $pid = getParamValue('pid');
    $svnr = getParamValue('svnr');
    $fname = getParamValue('fname');
    $lname = getParamValue('lname');
    $gender = getParamValue('gender');
    $age = getParamValue('age');
    $created_at = getParamValue('created_at');

    // Add patient
    $patient = $db->addPatient($pid, $svnr, $fname, $lname, $gender, $age, $created_at);

    if ($patient != false) {
        // patient stored successfully
    } else {
        // patient failed to store
        $response["error"] = "JSON Error occured in saving new patient.";
    }
```

DB_Functions.php

```
/**
 * Adding a new patient to mysql database
 */

public function addPatient($pid, $svnr, $fname, $lname, $gender, $age, $created_at) {
    $svnr = addslashes($svnr);
    $fname = addslashes($fname);
    $lname = addslashes($lname);

    $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO p_patient (p_id, p_svnr, p_firstname, p_lastname, p_gender, p_age, p_createdAt) VALUES ('$pid', '$svnr', '$fname', '$lname', '$gender', '$age', '$created_at')") or die(mysql_error());
    // check for successful store

    return $result;
}
```

And what I want is to connect it with a C# Application to insert into the values in a database. For example, I have a WPF Application with Textboxes and when I click on a button it should insert the values from the Textbox into the database. Has anyone an Example Code how to realize that?

Comment: You need to stop using `mysql_` functions, they have been deprecated for years and even removed from versions after 2015. Take a look at [PHP Data Objects](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: ok,thanks for the tip. Do you have any Link or example Code for me asked question?

Comment: I don't understand about C#, but just search for a way of doing http requests. You can pass your data with a request, just like a browser would do

Comment: I have searched but do not find useful code. Has anyone a good example or useful website?